# Parse JSON array to matrix using map

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I'm using swiftyJSON.

The data looks like the following but not really, there are about 700,000 elements.

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "one",
            "steak",
            -0.234
        ],
        [
            "cat",
            "pizza",
            1.9812
        ]
    ]
}
```

Currently I'm using this

```
let jsonArray:[JSON] = json["data"].arrayValue
for ( i=0; i<jsonArray.count; i++ )//number of data points
{
  A.append(jsonArray[i][0].string! )
  B.append(jsonArray[i][1].string! )
  X.append(jsonArray[i][2].float! )
}
```

but it is slow, I'd like to use `map` to speed things up to create individual arrays like shown or a M x N matrix.  Or how would I put this into a struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as below.

```
var A = jsonArray.map {$0[0].string!}
var B = jsonArray.map {$0[1].string!}
var X = jsonArray.map {$0[2].float!}
```

Still i am thinking how to do all above three steps in one line. But this may work for you.

Comment: Thanks. After 10 runs that improved things by about ~22%.